# How to output Site title on a sharepoint masterpage

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom masterpage in sharepoint and want to output the site title in a different part of the page. Currently I can see the site title which is outputted using the following code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

Apparently using

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

Should also output the title but is returning nothing. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Code you have mentioned are the Content Place Holders where you can replace the Content, You can place the register the below tag in the top the page and

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And place the below code to get the Title of the Page

```
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
```

If you want to do that in the master page level you can do with the below code

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" Visible="true">
 <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Unless you override the above content place holder you will get the Title of the Web Automatically

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the `ProjectProperty` control (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.aspx)

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
   <SharePoint:ProjectProperty property="Title" runat="server" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```